# MariaDB on XAMPP Windows not starting

Tags: windows, xampp, mariadb

I had installed XAMPP Version: 7.3.6 on Windows 10 months ago and until now everything working fine.

Today looks like MariaDB (MySQL) won't start.

Checking `error_log` there is error message:

```
2019-11-08 16:43:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-11-08 16:43:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-08 16:43:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-08 16:43:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-08 16:43:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-08 16:43:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 512M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-11-08 16:43:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-08 16:43:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-08 16:43:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-08 16:43:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-08 16:43:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-11-08 16:43:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-11-08 16:43:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.15 started; log sequence number 45307373705; transaction id 1089620
2019-11-08 16:43:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-11-08 16:43:52 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-08 16:43:52 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-11-08 16:43:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191108 16:43:52
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question since I've fixed this same issue on a coworker's laptop some days ago and today it happend to me. I'm tryint to reproduce the fix.

So there is no error message in `mysql_error` file.

But when taking a look at the data directory `C:\xampp\mysql\data`, it looks a little strange:

```
08/11/2019  16:43    <DIR>          .
08/11/2019  16:43    <DIR>          ..
04/11/2019  12:24    <DIR>          abac
24/09/2019  16:43    <DIR>          allmypicz
08/11/2019  16:43            16.384 aria_log.00000001
08/11/2019  16:43                52 aria_log_control
14/09/2019  16:53    <DIR>          ayudas
06/10/2019  08:32    <DIR>          erkcrm_28062019
16/09/2019  12:40    <DIR>          hdweb
08/11/2019  16:43        79.691.776 ibdata1
08/11/2019  16:43             2.137 ib_buffer_pool
08/11/2019  16:43       268.435.456 ib_logfile0
18/10/2019  19:49       268.435.456 ib_logfile1
12/09/2019  20:44    <DIR>          interno
08/11/2019  16:43               112 master-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a18@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.info
08/11/2019  16:43               112 master-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a18@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020c@003a@005cxampp@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.info
08/11/2019  16:43            16.255 master-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a18@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeded@000d.info
08/11/2019  16:38                 0 master-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a49@002025@0020@005berror@005d@0020mysqld@002eexe@003a@0020table@0020@0027@002e@005cabac@005cabac_logger@0027@0020is@0020marked@0020as@0020crashed@0020and@0020should@0020be@0020repaired@000d.info
08/11/2019  16:43               112 master-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a49@002025@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020checking@0020table@003a@0020@0020@0020@0027@002e@005cabac@005cabac_logger@0027@000d.info
08/11/2019  16:39               112 master-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a52@002025@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020checking@0020table@003a@0020@0020@0020@0027@002e@005cabac@005ctbl_migration@0027@000d.info
08/11/2019  16:43               112 master-version@003a@0020@002710@002e3@002e15@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.info
07/11/2019  11:10               934 multi-master.info
19/06/2019  19:28    <DIR>          mysql
08/11/2019  16:43               279 mysql-relay-bin-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a18@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.000003
08/11/2019  16:43               170 mysql-relay-bin-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a18@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.index
08/11/2019  16:43               279 mysql-relay-bin-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a18@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020c@003a@005cxampp@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.000003
08/11/2019  16:43               197 mysql-relay-bin-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a18@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020c@003a@005cxampp@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.index
08/11/2019  16:43               279 mysql-relay-bin-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a18@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeded@000d.000003
08/11/2019  16:43               163 mysql-relay-bin-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a18@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeded@000d.index
08/11/2019  16:43               279 mysql-relay-bin-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a49@002025@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020checking@0020table@003a@0020@0020@0020@0027@002e@005cabac@005cabac_logger@0027@000d.000003
08/11/2019  16:43               182 mysql-relay-bin-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a49@002025@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020checking@0020table@003a@0020@0020@0020@0027@002e@005cabac@005cabac_logger@0027@000d.index
08/11/2019  16:39               279 mysql-relay-bin-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a52@002025@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020checking@0020table@003a@0020@0020@0020@0027@002e@005cabac@005ctbl_migration@0027@000d.000002
08/11/2019  16:43               279 mysql-relay-bin-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a52@002025@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020checking@0020table@003a@0020@0020@0020@0027@002e@005cabac@005ctbl_migration@0027@000d.000003
08/11/2019  16:43             2.305 mysql-relay-bin-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a52@002025@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020checking@0020table@003a@0020@0020@0020@0027@002e@005cabac@005ctbl_migration@0027@000d.index
08/11/2019  16:43               279 mysql-relay-bin-version@003a@0020@002710@002e3@002e15@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.000003
08/11/2019  16:43               202 mysql-relay-bin-version@003a@0020@002710@002e3@002e15@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.index
08/11/2019  16:43             1.436 mysql_error.log
19/06/2019  19:28    <DIR>          performance_schema
19/06/2019  19:28    <DIR>          phpmyadmin
19/10/2019  13:35    <DIR>          portfolee
25/09/2019  13:08    <DIR>          programadoryiiframework
08/11/2019  16:43               181 relay-log-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a18@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.info
08/11/2019  16:43               208 relay-log-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a18@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020c@003a@005cxampp@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.info
08/11/2019  16:43               174 relay-log-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a18@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeded@000d.info
08/11/2019  16:43               193 relay-log-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a49@002025@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020checking@0020table@003a@0020@0020@0020@0027@002e@005cabac@005cabac_logger@0027@000d.info
08/11/2019  16:43               195 relay-log-2019@002d11@002d07@002011@003a10@003a52@002025@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020checking@0020table@003a@0020@0020@0020@0027@002e@005cabac@005ctbl_migration@0027@000d.info
08/11/2019  16:43               213 relay-log-version@003a@0020@002710@002e3@002e15@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.info
19/06/2019  19:28    <DIR>          test
              34 archivos    616.606.782 bytes
              14 dirs  62.695.202.816 bytes libres
```

You can see the "normal stuff", database directories, and data files, and then you see a lot of strange files containing lots of `@` in their name.

So what I did next was a cleanup of that directory:

```
08/11/2019  16:53    <DIR>          .
08/11/2019  16:53    <DIR>          ..
04/11/2019  12:24    <DIR>          abac
24/09/2019  16:43    <DIR>          allmypicz
08/11/2019  16:51            16.384 aria_log.00000001
08/11/2019  16:51                52 aria_log_control
14/09/2019  16:53    <DIR>          ayudas
08/11/2019  16:53    <DIR>          backup
06/10/2019  08:32    <DIR>          erkcrm_28062019
16/09/2019  12:40    <DIR>          hdweb
08/11/2019  16:51        79.691.776 ibdata1
08/11/2019  16:51             2.137 ib_buffer_pool
12/09/2019  20:44    <DIR>          interno
19/06/2019  19:28    <DIR>          mysql
19/06/2019  19:28    <DIR>          performance_schema
19/06/2019  19:28    <DIR>          phpmyadmin
19/10/2019  13:35    <DIR>          portfolee
25/09/2019  13:08    <DIR>          programadoryiiframework
19/06/2019  19:28    <DIR>          test
```

As you can see, a part from the databases directories, the only files I have left were:

```
08/11/2019  16:51            16.384 aria_log.00000001
08/11/2019  16:51                52 aria_log_control
08/11/2019  16:51        79.691.776 ibdata1
08/11/2019  16:51             2.137 ib_buffer_pool
```

So I have deleted those strange files and I have also deleted InnoDB log files that I knew from previous experiences that can they can cause issues sometimes.

Now I have started MariaDB from Xampp and works!

Don't know the cause for sure, my assumptions:

- Maybe a bad shutdown of the computer corrupted the InnoDB log files and after that it crashes when you try to start and it generates those "master/relay" files.

Maybe someone more familiar to MySQL/MariaDB could point the "cause".

Comment: Is the machine a Master?  Or a Slave?

Comment: I think Xampp default my.ini for MariaDB has replication disabled, I have no experience with that feature. But for "some reason" the server didn't wanted to start and all those additional files appeared in the folder. "Maybe" this could be caused by "wrong" start of MariaDB without adding the configuration file, and by default it starts with replication "On"

Comment: For some strange reason this keep showing up every few weeks. Wonder is something related to start-up or shut-down that breaks something.

Comment: (Replication is not something to have "on" by default.)

Comment: (Some of those files looked like they were generated by Replication.)

Comment: Yes but I don't "get" why sometimes it starts with it "ON" since it is the default XAMPP installation with some tweaking to the my.ini just for performance. And it happens only like once in a few weeks / months, randomly.